# Replace digits between 2 and 8 in length with specific character using regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex

We have a security issue where a specific field in a database has some sensitive information in it.  I need a way to detect numbers that are between 2 and 8 in length, replace the digits with a "filler" of the same length.

For instance:

```
Jim8888Dandy
Mike9999999999Thompson * Note: this is 10 in length and we don't want to replace the digits
123Area Code
Tim Johnson5555555
```

In these instances anytime we find a number that is between 2 and 8 (inclusive) then I want to replace/fill/substitute that value with the number 0 and keep the length of the original digits

End Result

```
   Jim0000Dandy
   Mike9999999999Thompson
   000Area Code
   Tim Johnson0000000
```

Is there an easy way to accomplish this using RegEx?

Comment: Do you want to do that in SQL Server or in the code?

Comment: It wouldn't be doable in pure regex, since the tools wasn't built to "count". However, in your programming language you could do something like match `\d{2,8}` and then replace with a callback function that counts the length of matched number.

Comment: @Szymon whatever is easiest to be honest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide a static evaluator method that would do the replacing. It replaces digits in the match with zeroes:

```
public static string Evaluate(Match m)
{
     return Regex.Replace(m.Value, "[0-9]", "0");
}
```

And then use it with this code:

```
string input = "9999999099999Thompson534543";
MatchEvaluator evaluator = new MatchEvaluator(Program.Evaluate);
string replaced = Regex.Replace(input, "(?:^|[^0-9])[0-9]{2,8}(?:$|[^0-9])", evaluator);
```

The regex is:

- `(?:^|[^0-9])` - should be at the start or preceeded by non-digit
- `[0-9]{2,8}` - the to capture between 2 and 8 digits
- `(?:$|[^0-9])` - should be at the end or followed by non-digit

Comment: This is very close.  It seems to be clipping the "n" from Thompson here is the result: 9999999099999Thompso000000  , notice the "n" is missing.

Comment: @kdunlapmo You're right. I changed the code to cater for that.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the clever regex department. This is not an efficient regex.

```
(?<=(?>(?'front'\d){0,7}))\d(?=(?'back'(?'-front'\d)){0,7}(?!\d))((?'-front')|(?'-back'))
```

Replace to `0`.

```
/(?<=(?>(?'front'\d){0,7})) # Measure how many digits we're behind.
  \d # This digit is matched
  (?=
    (?'back' # Measure how many digits we're in front of.
      (?'-front'\d)){0,7}
      # For every digit here, subtract one group from 'front',
      # As to assert we'll never go over the < 8 digit requirement.
  (?!\d) # no more digits
  )
 (
  (?'-front') # At least one capturing group left for 'front' or 'back'
 |(?'-back')  # for > 2 digits requirement.
 )/x
```

Comment: I tried this using RegEx Buddy and this was the result (based on the above examples) 
Jim8800Dandy

Mike9999900000Thompson

100Area Code

Tim Johnson5550000
Which is wrong

Comment: @kdunlapmo I've added an atomic group.